# Prove a certain integral expression of Bessel type for the Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: integral-equations, bessel-functions

I know that

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\,z\,\cos\theta}d\theta=J_0(z)
$$

where $J_n(z)$ denotes the Bessel function of the first kind of integral order.
My question is - how do I show that

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\,z(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta)}d\theta=J_0(z\sqrt{a^2+b^2})
$$

It is probably something  trivial, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any tips or hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since:
$$ a\cos\theta + b\sin\theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos\left(\theta-\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
the claim follows.